# Laravel where like on two strings

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to improve my search function.
Lets say for example the user types in "Letter contract" and in my database i have saved the following string "Letter employment contract". Using the following code will not return anything:

```
Letter::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%)->get()
```

Since the search is not looking into "Letter" alone and "Contract" alone in the context.
Anyways i can fix this?

**Update**
I tried the following code sample but still didn't get anywhere

```
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $this->attributes['q'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

        $model = $model->whereTranslationLike('title', "%{$this->attributes['q']}%");
       
            foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                $model->orWhereTranslationLike('title', "%{$value}%");
            }
```

Comment: Explode your search term. Loop over the elements and add a where like clause for each of them…

Comment: check the update version of my  question to see what i've tried

Answer (score 0):

A very naive (but simple) solution would be first to split the search string into individual words, then adding them to the query individually.

```
$words = explode(' ', $search);

$query = Letter::query();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$word}%");
}

$letters = $query->get();
```

This implementation doesn't scale very well, but it should get you thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Please check the update version of my  question to see what i've tried

Comment: Nothing wrong with simple…

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your first code but for me, if I wanted to do like you, my code will be like so

```
$letters = Letter::where("title", "LIKE", "%{$search}%")->get()
```

I wish this syntax helps you.